direction perpendicular to screen
I want to create a script that squeezes a curve along the vertical direction of the screen. Currently, I am using
`def get_view_direction():
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        region_3d = area.spaces.active.region_3d
        view_matrix = region_3d.view_matrix
        view_direction = view_matrix.to_3x3().inverted() @ mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0, -1.0))
        return view_direction
return None`

to get direction, but the effect is not very good,is there a better way?


What do you mean the effect is not very good? Can you actually show what the result is so we can get an idea of what might be the problem?

If it is extruded along the direction of the screen, the extruded part should not be visible in the view but should be a flat surface., my understanding is that. The above picture shows the effect of extrusion without rotating the view, it feels different from what I expected. Is there a better way?

You need to simply extrude in the direction of the camera, in geometry nodes it would look this way:


In Python the only tricky part is to calculate the position of the viewport camera:
from bpy import context as C, data as D
import bmesh

area = next(a for a in C.window.screen.areas if a.type=='VIEW_3D')
r3d = area.spaces[0].region_3d

cam_loc = r3d.view_matrix.inverted().translation
# you can test by spawning a UV sphere at cam_loc and scaling it

me = C.object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
geo = bmesh.ops.extrude_edge_only(bm, edges=bm.edges)['geom']

for v in (i for i in geo if type(i) == bmesh.types.BMVert):
    v.co += (v.co - cam_loc).normalized()
    
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)

